# Filter JSON Array in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the community and English is not my native language (I speak Spanish), but I will try to ask my question as clearly as possible.
I'm learning React and I am working on a component that imports a `JSON` file containing an array. I'm trying to figure out how to filter the array to be able to show information according to the url patch.

File React:

```
import React from 'react';
import Lista from '../../Arrays/Lista';


const Card = ({ match }) => {
    const product = Lista.filter( p => p.id === parseInt(match.params.id))
    return (
        <div>
                <h1> {product.title} </h1>
                <p>{product.description}</p>
                <img src={product.image} alt="imagen"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
export default Card;
```

File JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "FunkoPop Woody",
        "description" : "FunkoPop Woody Edicion Limitada",
        "price": "11.900",
        "image": "https://ripleycl.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fimagenes-sellers-mercado-ripley%2FImagenes-MIRAKL%2FMPM00002571116%2FMPM00002571116-1-F.jpg?w=750&h=555&ch=Width&auto=format&cs=strip&bg=FFFFFF&q=60&trimcolor=FFFFFF&trim=color&fit=fillmax&ixlib=js-1.1.0&s=95653b7ade9c0f60337f9b396fc0b544"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "FunkoPop Stitch",
        "description" : "FunkoPop Stitch Regular Edition",
        "price": "9.900",
        "image": "https://www.tiendawabro.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/2/3/2353.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "FunkoPop Jinx",
        "description": "FUnkoPop League of Legends",
        "price": "10.900",
        "image": "https://www.metalgame.cl/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/889698103053.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `Lista.find` instead of `Lista.filter`. Doing `filter` will return an array that contains _all_ matching items, `find` will return the first matching item

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me friend, have a nice day!